# Использовать свои горячие клавиши только при фокусе на консоле

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть программа которая перехватывает нажатие клавиш и делает какое либо действие

```
import keyboard
...
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + down', MoveDown)
```

Все работает, но работает даже если текущая программа не является главным окном. То есть я переключаюсь в word и все-равно работает перехват.

Как сделать так чтобы программа проверяла на саму себя активную. И работала только когда является главным окном. Пытаюсь поставить проверку на главное активное окно.. Но если я запускаю программу из VSCODE он является главным окном.  Из FAR Фар является главным окном. Но ни как не сама прога. Грубо говоря как определить что я нахожусь в своей программе сейчас а не в другой. Программа консольная.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python

Comment: @AlexanderChernin так не выйдет поймать именно консоль, когда она внутри того же VS Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ловить нажатия только в консоле, можно использовать модуль `msvcrt` ([документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html)). Но он не распознает нажатия клавиш типа `Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Alt`. Может `Esc`, некоторые из `F1-F12` и стрелки.

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        pressedKey = msvcrt.getwch()
        print("Key Pressed:", pressedKey, ord(pressedKey))
```

Можно сочетать его с модулем `keyboard`, чтобы получить механизм создания горячих клавиш. При этом использовать `msvcrt` как индикатор присутствия или отсутствия в консоле.

```
import msvcrt, keyboard

def check(method):
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()
        method()


def move_down():
    print('pressed Ctrl + Down')


keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + Down', lambda: check(move_down))
keyboard.wait()
```

Проблема данного способа в том, что комбинация `Ctrl + Down` может порой не срабатывать. Поскольку для `msvcrt.kbhit()` нажатие `Ctrl` ничего не значит. Но если начинать комбинацию со второй части, то есть `Down + Ctrl` - срабатывает всегда.

Следующий код в методе `check` необходим, чтобы очистить буфер от всех нажатых клавиш. Иначе условие `msvcrt.kbhit()` может сработать, когда консоль не является активным окном.

```
while msvcrt.kbhit():
    msvcrt.getch()
```